# Android loading array list of string arrays EOF Exception

Tags: java, android, inputstream, serializable, eofexception

I'm loading an ArrayList using ObjectInputStream in my application. Weirdly, it seems to have worked fine up until recently. I can't see what's causing it.

Here are the snippets of code involved:

```
protected ArrayList<String[]> LoadDetailList() {
    InputStream breedin;
    ArrayList<String[]> list = null;
    try {
        breedin = openFileInput("DetailList.ser");
        list = SaveAndLoad.doLoadDetailList(breedin);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Details List not found");
        list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    }
    Stored.addAllDetails(list);
    return list;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static ArrayList<String[]> doLoadDetailList(InputStream breedin) {
    ArrayList<String[]> h = null;

    try {

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(breedin);

        h = (ArrayList<String[]>) in.readObject();

        in.close();
        breedin.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return h;
}
```

And the exception:

```
10-01 14:58:07.130: W/System.err(23213): java.io.EOFException
10-01 14:58:07.130: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:98)
10-01 14:58:07.130: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.nextTC(ObjectInputStream.java:506)
10-01 14:58:07.130: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:778)
10-01 14:58:07.130: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1512)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:785)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:657)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1354)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1266)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1855)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:787)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2003)
10-01 14:58:07.135: W/System.err(23213):    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1960)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at admin.SaveAndLoad.doLoadDetailList(SaveAndLoad.java:309)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService.LoadDetailList(SendService.java:406)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService.getHolding(SendService.java:316)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService.processResponse(SendService.java:152)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService.sendMessage(SendService.java:128)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService$1.run(SendService.java:71)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService.startThread(SendService.java:93)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at services.server.SendService.onHandleIntent(SendService.java:49)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 14:58:07.140: W/System.err(23213):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: EOFException relates to reading from files.  EOF stands for End of File.

Comment: Is there anything in the file?

Comment: This one was thrown having just reinstalled the app. However, it has come up when there should definitely be something in the file. Are there any other likely causes? This does sound like a good possibility to go on.